# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Never' to return type 'String'

Tags: swift, string

I got this error for the last line in my getAPIArticleCategory function:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Never' to return type 'String'

[image: Error]

**Code:**

```
static func getAPIArticleCategory() -> String {

    var links: [String] = []

    for index in 16...21 {
        links.append(index.description)
        print("loopcategory", links)
    }

    return self.getDomainV3category() + links

}

static func getDomainV3category() -> String { 
    return self.getDomain()+"api/v3/article-category/"
}
```

Comment: Please include the `getDomainV3category()` function in your question as well.

Comment: Done @the4kman ....its just my domain link only

Comment: You are adding a String with [String]. you need to separate the data before adding it.Can you conform in which format you want to add so that we can setup a code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to append an array of strings to a string. You should join the `links` array with a separator of your choice.

```
return self.getDomainV3category() + links.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks friend... Its really help